# "I will not be coming" Vs. "I am not coming"

Tags: future-tense

Is there a difference in meaning and usage between the two sentences below?

(Both are happening in future)

> *A) I'm not coming in for work today.*
>
> *B) I will not be coming in for work today.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with @user3169. I would never use B with my boss, I think it has a very privileged tone. *Will* is very direct and implies that it is what is going to happen no matter what. With my boss I would always go for a less commanding tone, like that of A, or something even more passive like:

> I can't come in for work today.

Which implies that it's out of your control, instead of B which implies that you made the decision yourself.

Comment: Thank you. What if it's not asking for a day off and you're not supposed to come for work today. Is there any difference in using either? (Even as  subtle as 'more popular' or more natural in this context)

Comment: I mean you're just informing a co-worker that today you're not in.

Comment: I'd probably choose A. Or perhaps B if you contracted the *will not* into *won't*. The word *will* is just very definitive and should be used carefully when talking to your boss / coworkers / etc.